# Can't open blend project, want to remove corrupt objects without opening project

Tags: objects

First time here so hope it is the right place to ask this.
After a crash a blend project won't open again. I tried to open the auto saves and with different versions of blender but it crashes right after startup.
I tried to append scenes and found the objects in the project crash.
Is it possible in any way to delete objects from a projects without opening it
like deleting bad files from the append menu ?

This is really frustrating as all the "saves as" of this project won't open. Many days of work :(
Any help will be much appreciated
Thank you

Comment: have you tried setting up a new file and accessing the contents of the corrupt file via File->Append?

Comment: yes i did but i cant delete any files from the append file browser ... 
appending the other objects and building the scenes again will take very long as it was a pretty complex project ..